# android thread startIntent in 5 second and press Home key

Tags: android, android-intent, android-homebutton

step to show the problem:

1 create android hello world projet

2 create Activity2, just copied from MainActivity,declared it in manifest.xml

3 in MainActivity.onCreate method  add code belows

```
mContext = MainActivity.this;
new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, Activity2.class);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
            finish(); // -----> notice this
        }
    }.start();
```

4 start this app , and launcher in MainActivity

5 before it goto Activity2 ,press Home key

6 a few sec later, it auto jump to Activity2 .

but if I comment finish() same steps ,but not jump

Why is that so?

Comment: Are you trying to code a splash screen?

Comment: what you want exactly ?

Comment: i want to finish MainActivity and not auto return to Activity2

Comment: So then finish your Activity 2 if you don't use it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Is it finishing the activity? 
If so then try doing this:

```
try{
    sleep(100);
    wait += 100;
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("EXc=" + e);
} finally {
    startActivity(new Intent(frame.this,main.class));
    finish();
};
welcomeThread.start();
```